# Anyone get XRDP working on Kubuntu 16.04 desktop?

Tags: kubuntu, xrdp

I'm trying to get XRDP working on Kubuntu 16.04 desktop.
All I get when I try to RDP from Windows 7 is a gray screen.
Anyone been able to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue and I did find a work around. I dropped the resolution from full screen to anything below 1920x1080

I have kubuntu 16.04.3 fresh install and used [Ubuntu 16.04: Connect to KDE desktop environment via XRDP instructions.](https://www.hiroom2.com/2017/09/30/ubuntu-1604-xrdp-kde-en/)

This dose work but it forces a very small screen. I am still looking for a way to run at full screen or at least higher resolution.

**Update:** Changing the resolution has some odd results. When I first tried 1680x1050 it did not work on windows 7 so I tried it on windows 10 and it worked fine. I was even able to right click the top of the window to get full screen or smart resizing options and both worked. So I tried it on windows 7 again and this time it worked but on windows 7 there is no full screen or smart resizing option so the task bars overlaps with windows 7 task bar. After getting success I tried to repeat the steps again to post what I found out here and got different results. I have rebooted server and can not get the resize or full screen to work again. the window seems to be stuck at about 600x800. rough guess on resolution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/790616)

Comment: While I agree it is not 100% fix it dose solve the gray screen. I really feel like I do not get this site.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/790616)

Comment: The link was not the answer it was a reference to my setup so that one could see how close it might match to there problem. The work around was the part about adjusting the resolution.

Comment: @waltinator how does it not answer the question? It provides a workaround. Not a very good workaround, granted, but one that Startblight seems to have chosen to use, so it might be useful to others with the same issue.

Comment: @derHugo the presence of a link in an answer doesn't make it bad. The answer, even before the edit, was useful without the link: it suggested lowering the resolution as a workaround.